# ng-init Used Twice Inside ng-repeat, Only First ng-init is Being Evaluated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-init

See the below code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(6) track by $index" ng-init="loopNumber = $index">
    <td class="border-right" style="width:10%;" ng-init="day = monthOfData[7 * loopNumber]">
        <p>{{day}}</p>
    </td>
    <td class="border-right" style="width:10%;" ng-init="day = monthOfData[7 * loopNumber+1]">
        <p>{{day}}</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I expect where {{day}} is being used, the output would be something like:

```
1
2
```

However, the output is:

```
1
1
```

AngularJS seems to be skipping the second use of ng-init inside the ng-repeat. Is this a performance feature of AngularJS? I am using ng-init to save re-evulating the same expression.

Comment: The first loop, I assume `loopNumber == 0` so your value for `7*loopNumber` is 0 and then you add 1 to it.... This isn't an angular issue it's a code issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, this usage of `ng-init` is wrong. To initialize means to set the start value of a variable, so with your last use of `ng-init` you're initializing a variable that already has a value and "overwriting" what was already there.

In more detail: The first instance of `ng-init` sets `loopNumber = 0` because arrays and indexes start with 0, not 1. Then you set `day = 0` -- at that point, both instances of `{{day}}` in your html would evaluate to 0. Then lastly you set `day = 1`, therefore the output of `{{day}}` becomes 1.

Note that this applies to *all the places* in your page where you used `{{day}}`, not just the lines after the third `ng-init`. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ng-init` (such as aliasing special properties of `ng-repeat`) and this is not one of those cases.

An example of how the code could work without `ng-init`:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(6) track by $index">
    <td>
      <p>{{ monthOfData[7 * $index] }}</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>{{ monthOfData[7 * $index + 1] }}</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Or alternatively, since your `td` blocs are very similar, we could add a second loop like so:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(6) track by $index" ng-init="loopNumber = $index">
    <td ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(2) track by $index" ng-init="var = $index">
      <p>{{ monthOfData[7 * loopNumber + var] }}</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Note how in this second example `ng-init` is used to alias the two instances of `$index` referring to the two different loops. This was not needed in the first example and we can use `$index` directly when evaluating the expressions.